# Duda con resultado consulta sql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo esta consulta y necesito saber si me está devolviendo correctamente el nombre y el código de los clientes han comprado algún producto que nos da el beneficio mínimo con la venta

```
SELECT nombre_cliente, clientes.codigo_cliente
FROM clientes,pedidos,detallepedidos,productos,(
  SELECT MIN(precio_venta - precio_proveedor) AS beneficio FROM productos
   ) AS a WHERE clientes.codigo_cliente = pedidos.codigo_cliente
  AND pedidos.codigo_pedido = detallepedidos.codigo_pedido
  AND detallepedidos.codigo_producto = productos.codigo_producto
  GROUP BY codigo_cliente
  ORDER BY nombre_cliente;
```

Comment: Cuál gestor de base de datos usas? `Microsoft SQL`, `MySQL`...? si es `MySQL` puedes probar tu query en `phpmyadmin`, en la pestaña `SQL`.

Comment: mysql si gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo te faltaba la condición de que, además de todo lo que ya habías tenido en cuenta, el beneficio mínimo que has calculado también fuera el del producto:

```
SELECT nombre_cliente, clientes.codigo_cliente
FROM clientes,pedidos,detalle_pedidos,productos,(
  SELECT MIN(precio_venta - precio_proveedor) AS beneficio FROM productos
   ) AS a WHERE clientes.codigo_cliente = pedidos.codigo_cliente
  AND pedidos.codigo_pedido = detalle_pedidos.codigo_pedido
  AND detalle_pedidos.codigo_producto = productos.codigo_producto
  AND beneficio=precio_venta-precio_proveedor -- esta era la línea que te faltaba
  GROUP BY codigo_cliente
  ORDER BY nombre_cliente;
```

En cualquier caso, para que la consulta se ejecute mucho más rápido, te recomiendo que hagas uso del producto interno (JOIN).  El producto cartesiano combina todo con todo y finalmente se queda con lo que indicas en el WHERE, es muy ineficiente y, en consecuencia, lento.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre_cliente,codigo_cliente  FROM (
    SELECT codigo_producto FROM productos
      WHERE precio_venta-precio_proveedor=(
        SELECT MIN(precio_venta-precio_proveedor)
          FROM productos
      )
  ) c1 JOIN detalle_pedidos USING(codigo_producto)
  JOIN pedidos USING(codigo_pedido)
  JOIN clientes USING(codigo_cliente)
  ORDER BY nombre_cliente;
```

Si además utilizáramos las tablas intermedias proyectadas (únicamente con los campos que necesitemos), el servidor tendría que cargar en memoria muchos menos datos. Fíjate que sólo hay que abrir paréntesis antes de cada tabla y detallar los campos útiles. La consulta es más larga pero, en cambio, es mucho más eficiente y rápida porque tiene que llevar muchos menos datos del disco a la memoria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre_cliente,codigo_cliente  FROM (
    SELECT codigo_producto FROM (
        SELECT codigo_producto,precio_venta,precio_proveedor
          FROM productos
      ) productos
      WHERE precio_venta-precio_proveedor=(
        SELECT MIN(precio_venta-precio_proveedor)
          FROM productos
      )  
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT codigo_producto,codigo_pedido
      FROM detalle_pedidos
  ) detalle_pedidos USING(codigo_producto)
  JOIN (
    SELECT codigo_pedido,codigo_cliente FROM pedidos
  ) pedidos USING(codigo_pedido)
  JOIN (
    SELECT codigo_cliente,nombre_cliente FROM clientes
  ) clientes USING(codigo_cliente)
  ORDER BY nombre_cliente;
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil.